# Google Maps API Directions Service return directions in xml format

Tags: javascript, json, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've succesfully done the process of getting the directions:

```
function getRoute(){
    var formato = $('#formato-bizis-select').val();
    var start = $('#input-origen').val();

    $.post("index.php/calcular-ruta", $('#bizis-form').serialize(), function(data){
        var end = data.lat + "," + data.long;
        var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        }
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

And I know, from the documentation, that you can access data in XML or JSON format from this different URLs:

- JSON: *http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/**json**?parameters*
- XML: *http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/**xml**?parameters*

But, the in the ***directionService.route()*** method I don't know how to include the URL in the request for indicate the formatI want.

Comment: Why don't you use the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 DirectionsService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)?  It provides the data required for the DirectionsRenerer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing two different APIs:

- The [Directions Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) is part of the JavaScript Maps API and is what you use in JavaScript code.
- The [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) is an HTTP API for use from server-side code.

The Directions API does have options to return either XML or JSON data to your server-side code.

But since you are writing JavaScript here, you aren't using the Directions API, you're using the Directions Service. This doesn't provide JSON or XML or anything like that, it gives you a JavaScript object that you can use directly in your JavaScript code.

In your code, `response` is a JavaScript object. You can use the Developer Tools in your browser to look at it directly and see its properties, and you can write JavaScript code to access it directly without having to parse JSON or XML.

Comment: Ok, understand! I was also succesful using the Directions API through a curl call in PHP (using PHP Slim framework), but I was having troubles passing the response from the Directions API to the Map in Javascript, because I thougth both of the API's returned the same object. Now I see they don't...

Comment: @daniegarcia254 How did you then solve this? I'm facing the same issue, have you done any conversion from the Directions API response to JS compatible format?

Comment: @Madhavan.V sorry, I just don't remember, but this is the affected file from the project, hope it helps: https://github.com/daniegarcia254/bizi-meteo/blob/c5b964b28e4c2bdfd33bfe9147b119d40823775f/www/templates/main.php